# How to get OneGet/PackageManagement to work on Windows 10 Home?

Tags: windows-10, chocolatey, windows-packagemanagement

I'm trying to install Google Chrome by OneGet. As I understand OneGet should be default package manager in Windows 10.

I'm typing `get-command -Module OneGet` and gets nothing.
`find-package chrome` returns "No match was found for the specified search criteria".

[image]

How to install Chrome or VLC by OneGet, or how to install OneGet? 
Or there is no reason to use OneGet in Win10 and better to install chocolatey (it works fine for me)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you need to use `-Provider Chocolatey`. However I will tell you that you should probably stick to using choco.exe until you see an announcement (newsletter or on Chocolatey.org front page) that the OneGet Chocolatey Provider is ready. Otherwise I believe you will be using the CTP from last April 2014 (not a typo).

Comment: find-package chrome -Provider Chocolatey
solved my problem